# std::cout doesn't print letters after \n in QNX

Tags: c++, string, qnx

I want to print a list of items stored in a single string. I don't know why the last item is skipped!

Do you have an idea why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string string_test{"Item1\nItem2\nItem3"};
  std::cout << string_test;

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Item1
Item2
```

Comment: QNX once again...

Comment: Did you try to flush the buffer at the very end, just to be sure?

Comment: Most likely the buffer hasn't flushed.  Add `std::cout.flush();`

Comment: Yup once again :'(

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://cpp.sh/9d7np

Comment: @ypnos yes I did

Comment: @Slava you need QNX

Comment: @H.Ilyas no I do not

Comment: @NathanOliver that didn't help either

Comment: @Slava The same code works fine in Linux, but fails to output the correctly in QNX

Comment: Have you validated that issue is C++ specific? For example `echo -n` does it output fine?

Comment: I already ask for what appends if adding a final \n or writing on stderr, no answer ;)

Comment: @bruno adding `\n` at the end prints Item3. The thing is I need the string without `\n` at the end.

Comment: @H.Ilyas and without the added \n but on stderr ?

Comment: @bruno surprisingly `std::cerr` works fine!

Comment: @H.Ilyas yes and no, on _stderr_ the flush is automatic, now one have to understand why forcing the flush on _stdout_ doesn't work and how to make it working

Comment: @bruno I agree. Please share if you get something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a reported bug in line-buffered stream output on QNX version 7.0.3.

[Source](http://community.qnx.com/sf/discussion/do/listPosts/projects.core_os/discussion.newcode.topc27612)

Answer (score 1):

Under POSIX 2017, the C++ implementation is **not** required to flush the program's standard output at program termination<sup>1</sup>. Yours doesn't. You need to do it manually:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string string_test{"Item1\nItem2\nItem3"};
    std::cout << string_test << std::flush;
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup>

> #### [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)
>
> As required by the ISO C standard, using return from `main()` has the same behavior (other than with respect to language scope issues) as calling `exit()` with the returned value. Reaching the end of the `main()` function has the same behavior as calling `exit(0)`.
>
> [...]
>
> The `_Exit()`  and `_exit()` functions shall not call functions registered with `atexit()` nor any registered signal handlers. **[Option Start]**  Open streams shall not be flushed. **[Option End]**  Whether open streams are closed (without flushing) is implementation-defined. Finally, the calling process shall be terminated with the consequences described below.

Comment: I did it that! No result

Comment: "The C++ implementation is required to flush the program standard output" I would like to see a quote for this claim

Comment: @H.Ilyas what appends if you add a final \n or write on _stderr_ ?

Comment: @YSC I bet `std::cout` destructor does flush, so there could be issue with output from destructor of a static object but this is not a case.

Comment: @Slava [Old docs](https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.0/dinkum_en/cpp/iostream.html) but they do claim to do this. Interestingly I can't immediately find any requirement for this in the standard

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `std::cerr` rather than `std::cout`, on `std::cerr` the flush is automatic

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string string_test{"Item1\nItem2\nItem3"};
    std::cerr << string_test;

    return 0;
}
```